# How sensible is it to pass functions to initialisation lists in a constructor?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class Engine that looks a bit like this:

```
class Engine
{
  public:
  private:
     Game * m_pGame;
}
```

And then I want to use an initialisation list for it's constructor:

```
// Forward declaration of the function that will return the
// game instance for this particular game. 
extern Game * getGame();

// Engine constructor
Engine::Engine():
  m_pGame(getGame())
{

}
```

Is that initialiser for `m_pGame` sensible?

What I mean is - is it OK/good practice to use a function to initialise a member variable in a constructor?

Comment: You're not "passing a function", you're calling it, and passing its result as the member initializer. That's fine. It's probably more common to call a function that takes some arguments, passing the constructor's arguments to the function which does something with them and returns some result.

Comment: agree re: "passing a function". it just seemed long winded to type that as part of the question. Later on I used the phrase "use a function".

Comment: "How sensible is it to call functions in initialization lists in a constructor?" is exactly the same number of words and characters

Comment: lol you are right i totally agree - feel free to change my question title :-)

Comment: A warning, however.  Do not try to call virtual methods in the initializer list (or in the body of the constructor)  You will be executing a method on an uninitialized derived object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initialiser lists don't care how the values get there. What you have to worry about is making sure that a reasonable value is provided. If getGame() is sure to return a valid pointer, then there's no reason why this would be a problem.

Perhaps a better question is, why don't you call getGame first and pass that in as an argument? eg:

```
Engine::Engine(Game* game):
  m_pGame(game)
{
}

// later...
Engine* the_engine = new Engine(getGame());
```

That gives you more flexibility over how you configure an Engine in future, and doesn't hard-code the dependency on the getGame function.

Comment: This is what I had originally actually. but i didn't understand what made it better/worse than the other design.

Comment: In terms of flexibility, it's usually better to resolve dependencies outside the constructor. (Which is basically what is these days called 'Dependency Injection'.) The disadvantage is that there is less encapsulation (as Engine can no longer operate without you having to tell it which Game to use). So you have to weigh up pros and cons.